# What is the easiest way to open Start menu directory?

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

On Windows XP I had to right-click the Start button and choose Open or Explorer. How to do that on Windows 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on Start orb -> Right click on All Programs and then click on Open/Open All Users.

[image]

[image]

Comment: the image links are broken